# .htaccess http to https specific domain multiple domains redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I'm trying to use that, it works but every domain on my single IP / same server is also trying to go to HTTPS and I only have one SSL valid for one domain.

How can I specify for the rewrite rule to only apply to the one particular domain?

This one appears to have a redirect loop but it works as far as isolating only one domain to be redirected

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: This looks fine. Check in chrome Dev tool what redirects you are getting.

Comment: I'm not sure if I explained my situation thoroughly. I have one IP, one server, but several domains/folders, the primary domain has an SSL certificate, it is only valid for one domain. I want to redirect only that domain. The code above redirects every website to the primary domain.

Comment: Right but when you have `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]` you should not get any redirect loop.

Comment: `# Redrect: http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# Redrect: https to http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain1.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain2.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`


This is not working for 2 domains, works for 1 domain. Can you suggest how to make it work for 2 domains?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for an entire domain

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: This isn't it. I have multiple domains on the same ip, the other domains are folders. I used a htaccess rewrite where the domains appear with their own name eg. not a subdomain or subfolder of the primary domain.

Comment: I'll probably just do a redirect via php to the https page something like if servername != https sort of deal